# How do JAXB handles attribute in tag?

Tags: html, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

Suppose I have the following xml:

```
<root>
<tag1>value1</tag1>
<tag2 attr1="somevalue"></tag2>
</root>
```

I want to know how the JAXB handles the attribute of any tag, when it converts from xml to any any object. (I mean when it does unmarshalling)