# JAXB. Get boolean from string

Tags: java, jaxb

In my XML I have

```
<myelem required="false"/>
```

How I can read the `required` attribute as a boolean? I can read it as `String` and inside a getter do this: `return new Boolean(required)`
But maybe there are some more elegant ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JAXB handles attribute in tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845484/how-do-jaxb-handles-attribute-in-tag)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just simply use `boolean` for the member in your Java class:

```
@XmlAttribute
private boolean required;
```

Or, if you use getter-setter style of mapping:

```
@XmlAttribute
public boolean isRequired() {
    return required;
}
```

The JAXB unmarshaller is able to interpret `"true"` and `"false"` strings in the XML document as `boolean` value.

**UPDATE:**

I tested this with the following classes:

***test/MyElem.java***:

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="myelem")
public class MyElem {

    private boolean required;

    @XmlAttribute
    public boolean isRequired() {
        return required;
    }

    public void setRequired(boolean value) {
        required = value;
    }

}
```

***Test.java***:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import java.io.*;
import test.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyElem.class);
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            Object o = u.unmarshal( new File( "test.xml" ) );   
            System.out.println(((MyElem)o).isRequired());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And with the following input (*test.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myelem required="true"/>
```

I get the correct result on the console:

```
true
```

Comment: It will work when input is **<myelem>false</myelem>** not when false is passed as an attribute value.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi: Nope, that's why I put the `@XmlAttribute` annotation on the member. It maps a member to an XML attribute, [see the documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html).

Comment: +1 - I updated your answer to simplify the example code.  I hope you do not mind.

Comment: Kudos for adding the test, I used the code to test the marshalling of my own annotated objects.